# Direct links in Azure Blob Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

A bit of a background. I want my users to be able to click a link in our application and have their locally installed Azure Blob Storage Explorer take them to a blob that the link specifies.

A newer version of the Explorer can actually produce Direct Links to any kind of resouce. I.e. I can click on a "directory" or a file inside a container and there'd be a COpy Direct Link, which copies into my clipboard something like this:

```
storageexplorer://?v=2&tenantId=....&type=blobPath&path=....%2F&container=....&serviceEndpoint=https%3A%2F%2F.....blob.core.windows.net%2F&storageAccountId=%2Fsubscriptions%2F....%2FresourceGroups%2F....%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Storage%2FstorageAccounts%2F...&subscriptionId=....
```

(I had to redact out all the private information)

This URL activates the Azure Blob Storage Explorer, and I get a choice of options, including attaching the folder (or downloading the file, if I took a direct link to a file). I choose the account (which is by then already logged in), and the folder actually gets attached, however when it's attempted opened or refreshed, I get authorization error messages with code "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" and text "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission."

So, how do I make this work? My intent is to just give people a URL to a location, which they should be able to open with their own credentials. I have a feeling that the direct link that I get from the explorer somehow requires a different kind of authentication then the explorer itself can perform.

Comment: FYI this is off-topic here, as it's a tool-specific question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when it's attempted opened or refreshed, I get authorization
> error messages with code "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" and text
> "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission."

The direct link that you get from Azure Blob Storage Explorer requires the user to have the necessary permissions to access the linked resource. If the user does not have the required permissions.

- To access and read data from resources such as blobs, you must have been assigned a role that grants you the necessary permissions. The **`Storage Blob Data contributor role`** is the required role to list or download blobs.

To assign roles

Azure portal -> subscription->Access control (IAM) -> add role assignment -> add reader role.

**Portal:**
[image]

Once I pasted the direct link in the browser I could see options like below.

**Storage explorer:**
[image]

I clicked attach the container to move next state.

[image]

Now, Clicked my account with assigned role permissions.

[image]

[image]

Now, I've successfully added a new connection.

[image]

Also, make sure your storage account Networking is enabled to all networks.

**Reference:**

[Azure Storage Explorer troubleshooting guide - Azure | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-storage/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows#azure-rbac-permissions-issues)

**Update:**

You need to enable the **Default to Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal** in the Azure portal to authenticate with Entra ID authentication.

[image]

To attach the directory in the storage explorer the user needs **`Storage blob data contributor`** role

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. However, in my case everything looks the same as on your screenshots, just that at the very end I get the access error instead of seeing the contents. Even though I am the same user who has copied the direct link and I obviously have the access to the container through the Storage Accounts tree under the subscription.

Comment: If you still facing issue persists you can raise a new request in GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues

Comment: Would be good, however my problem is not solved, if you read my comment above.

Comment: What is your version of Microsoft azure storage explorer?

Comment: Try to use the new version, I'm using the `1.32.1` version.

Comment: 1.32.1 (96)
AzCopy ver.: 10.20.1
Win x64

Comment: I figured out make sure in the portal storage account -> configuration  enable the `Default to Microsoft Entra authorization` in the Azure portal
https://i.imgur.com/fPQ7g9N.png

Comment: I have the same issue as before, sadly... even after logging off and on again and doing everything from the beginning...

Comment: Have you enabled Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal?

Comment: If it is disable the storage account only authenticate with account key only.

Comment: Indeed, I have: https://imgur.com/a/VMkFNf2

Comment: Try to add `Storage blob data contributor` role to your storage account and try again with direct URL because it working fine.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot like me https://i.imgur.com/vB7Rf0G.png When I try the same process with the role it works fine for me.

Comment: When I remove the role and tried the same link I got same error like you see here https://i.imgur.com/gVNuBKC.png

Comment: Edited answer hope it will address your issue.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Amazing - thanks a lot for taking the time to research this, since you've included that in the answer, I'm marking it as accepted. Thank you!